# Is it possible to show Error Message in VOID type for webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to Web Api 2 , I want to show some message if i hit Exception , I know that VOID is a non return type, I tried with **HttpResponseMessage** but it is not working or showing the  **"Error Message"** , is that any way to show message ?

My code is as below

```
 public void Post(int id)
 {

        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
          //some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response2 = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error message");
            ErrId = 999;
        }
 }
```

Comment: If you hit the exception, then ex.Message should show you what you need.

Comment: @Wheels73 can show some example on the exception part ?

Comment: Just replace "Error Message" with ex.Message.

Comment: the use `public void Post(int id)` seems a little suspicious. this looks like a GET method named "post". are you sure you are actually calling the proper function?

Comment: What prevents you from returning the `response2` result you've created in the `catch` block? If successful, return Created() or Ok().

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web api 2, then I would use `IHttpActionResult` as the return type, which allows you to do something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(int id)
{
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
          //some code
          return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error message");
        }
 }
```

However, it must be noted that by default Web API has a built-in exception handler and logger that will automatically return a 500 response code for any exception, so the code above is potentially redundant unless you are catching a custom exception. Lastly the code above does not log the exception.